# Number of substrings with count of each character as k

Tags: string, data-structures, substring

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-substrings-count-character-k/

Given a string and an integer k, find number of substrings in which all the different characters occurs exactly k times.

Looking for a solution in O(n), using two pointers/sliding window approach. I'm able to find only longest substrings satisfying this criteria but not substrings within that long substring.

For ex: ababbaba, k = 2 
My solution finds abab, ababba etc, but not bb within ababba.

Can someone help me with the logic?

Comment: Also, would like to know if this can be done in O(n) or need O(n2) algorithm

Answer (score 6):

If you could edit your question to include your solution code, I'd be happy to help you with that.

For now **I'm sharing my solution code (in java) which runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. I've added enough comments to make the code self explanatory. Nonetheless the logic for the solution is as follows:

*As you correctly pointed out, the problem can be solved using sliding window approach (with variable window size). The solution below considers all possible sub-strings, using nested for loops for setting start and end indices. For each sub-string, we check if every element in the sub-string occurs exactly k times.*

*To avoid recalculating the count for every sub-string, we maintain the count in a map, and keep putting new elements in the map as we increment the end index (slide the window). This ensures that our solution runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) and not O(n<sup>3</sup>).*

*To further improve efficiency, we only check the count of individual elements if the sub-string's size matches our requirement. e.g. for n unique elements (keys in the map), the size of required sub-string would be n*k. If the sub-string's size doesn't match this value, there's no need to check how many times the individual characters occur.*

```java
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Java program to count the number of perfect substrings in a given string. A
 * substring is considered perfect if all the elements within the substring
 * occur exactly k number of times.
 * 
 * @author Codextor
 */

public class PerfectSubstring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "aabbcc";
        int k = 2;
        System.out.println(perfectSubstring(s, k));

        s = "aabccc";
        k = 2;
        System.out.println(perfectSubstring(s, k));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of perfect substrings in the given string for the
     * specified value of k
     * 
     * @param s The string to check for perfect substrings
     * @param k The number of times every element should occur within the substring
     * @return int The number of perfect substrings
     */
    public static int perfectSubstring(String s, int k) {

        int finalCount = 0;

        /*
         * Set the initial starting index for the subarray as 0, and increment it with
         * every iteration, till the last index of the string is reached.
         */
        for (int start = 0; start < s.length(); start++) {

            /*
             * Use a HashMap to store the count of every character in the subarray. We'll
             * start with an empty map everytime we update the starting index
             */
            Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();

            /*
             * Set the initial ending index for the subarray equal to the starting index and
             * increment it with every iteration, till the last index of the string is
             * reached.
             */
            for (int end = start; end < s.length(); end++) {
                /*
                 * Get the count of the character at end index and increase it by 1. If the
                 * character is not present in the map, use 0 as the default count
                 */
                char c = s.charAt(end);
                int count = frequencyMap.getOrDefault(c, 0);
                frequencyMap.put(c, count + 1);

                /*
                 * Check if the length of the subarray equals the desired length. The desired
                 * length is the number of unique characters we've seen so far (size of the map)
                 * multilied by k (the number of times each character should occur). If the
                 * length is as per requiremets, check if each element occurs exactly k times
                 */
                if (frequencyMap.size() * k == (end - start + 1)) {
                    if (check(frequencyMap, k)) {
                        finalCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return finalCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if every value in the map is equal to k
     * 
     * @param map The map whose values are to be checked
     * @param k   The required value for keys in the map
     * @return true if every value in the map is equal to k
     */
    public static boolean check(Map<Character, Integer> map, int k) {
        /*
         * Iterate through all the values (frequency of each character), comparing them
         * with k
         */
        for (Integer i : map.values()) {
            if (i != k) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For a given value `k` and a string `s` of *length `n`* with *alphabet size `D`*, we can solve the problem in **O(n*D)**.

We need to find sub-strings with each character having exactly k-occurences

- Minimum size of such sub-string = k (when only one character is there)
- Maximum size of such sub-string = k*D (when all characters are there)

So we will check for all sub-strings of sizes in range [k, k*D]

```py
from collections import defaultdict

ALPHABET_SIZE = 26

def check(count, k):
    for v in count.values():
        if v != k and v != 0:
            return False
    return True

def countSubstrings(s, k):
    total = 0
    for d in range(1, ALPHABET_SIZE + 1):
        size = d * k
        count = defaultdict(int)
        l = r = 0
        while r < len(s):
            count[s[r]] += 1
            # if window size exceed `size`, then fix left pointer and count
            if r - l + 1 > size:
                count[s[l]] -= 1
                l += 1
            # if window size is adequate then check and update count
            if r - l + 1 == size:
                total += check(count, k)
            r += 1  
    return total

def main():
    string1 = "aabbcc"
    k1 = 2
    print(countSubstrings(string1, k1))        # output: 6
    
    string2 = "bacabcc"
    k2 = 2
    print(countSubstrings(string2, k2))        # output: 2

main()
```

Comment: Isn't this O(N*D*D) solution considering that the check method takes O(D) time?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a O(n) solution but I can give you a O(k*n) solution (better than O(n^2) mentioned in the geeksforgeeks page).

The idea is that max no. elements are 26. So, we don't have to check all the substrings, we just have to check substrings with length<=26*k (26*k length is the case when all elements will occur k times. If length is more than that then at least one element will have to occur at least k+1 times). Also, we need to check only those substrings whose lengths are a factor of k.

So, check all 26*k*l possible substrings! (assuming k<<l). Thus, solution is O(k*n) but with a bit high constant (26).

Answer (score 0):

There are few observation which will help optimize the solution

1. Notice that, you don't need to check every possible size substrings, you just need to check substrings of size k, 2*k, 3*k so on up to ALPHABET_SIZE * k (remember **Pigeonhole principle**)
2. You can pre-calculate frequency of alphabets till certain index from any end and later you can use it to find the frequency of alphabets between any two indexes in O(26)

**C++ Implementation of your problem in O(n * ALPHABET_SIZE^2)**

I have added **comments** and **diagrams** to help you out in understanding code quickly

[diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lq4J.jpg)

[diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T41Ls.jpg)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);

    int n, k;
    string s;

    cin >> n >> k;
    cin >> s;

    ll cnt = 0;
    /**
     * It will be storing frequency of each alphabets
     **/
    vector<int> f(ALPHABET_SIZE, 0);
    /**
     * It will store alphabets frequency till that index
     **/
    vector<vector<int>> v;

    v.push_back(f);

    /**
     * Scan array from left to right and calculate the frequency of each alphabets till that index
     * Now push that frequency array in v
     * This loop will run for n times
     **/
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        f[s[i - 1] - 'a']++;
        v.push_back(f);
    }

    /**
     * This loop will run for k times
     **/
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        /**
         * start is the lower bound (left end from where window will start sliding)
         **/
        int start = i;
        /**
         * end is the upper bound (right end till where window will be sliding)
         **/
        int end = (n / k) * k + i;

        if (end > n)
        {
            end -= k;
        }

        /**
         * This loop will run for n/k times
         **/
        for (int j = start; j <= end; j += k)
        {
            /**
             * This is a ALPHABET_SIZE * k size window
             * It will be sliding between start and end (inclusive)
             * This loop will run for at most ALPHABET_SIZE times
             **/
            for (int d = j + k; d <= min(ALPHABET_SIZE * k + j, end); d += k)
            {
                /**
                 * A flag to check weather substring is valid or not
                 **/
                bool flag = true;
                /**
                 * Check if frequencies at two different indexes differ only by zero or k (element wise)
                 * Note that frequencies at two different index can't be same
                 * This loop will run for ALPHABET_SIZE times
                 **/
                for (int idx = 0; idx < ALPHABET_SIZE; idx++)
                {
                    if (abs(v[j][idx] - v[d][idx]) != k && abs(v[j][idx] - v[d][idx]) != 0)
                    {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Increase the total count if flag is true
                 **/
                if (flag)
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print the total count
     **/
    cout << cnt;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain why you added an empty frequency to v in the beginning? and then starting from i=t to <=n.

Comment: @NeoRavi, Suppose you want to calculate the frequency of alphabets from index i to j, you can calculate it like freq[k] = v[j][k] - v[i-1][k] where 0<=k<ALPHABET_SIZE. In case if i = 0, you actually don't need to subtract v[i-1][k]. To avoid checking for i = 0, you can add an empty frequency to v in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

if you want solution in simple way and not worried about time complexity. Here is the solution.

```
public class PerfecSubstring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = "aabbcc";
        int k = 2;
        System.out.println(perfect(st, k));
    }

    public static int perfect(String st, int k) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = st.length(); j > i; j--) {
                String sub = st.substring(i, j);
                if (sub.length() > k && check(sub, k)) {
                    System.out.println(sub);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static boolean check(String st, int k) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
            Character c = st.charAt(i);
            map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
        }
        return map.values().iterator().next() == k &&  new HashSet<>(map.values()).size() == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer I did in C#, with O(n^2) complexity. I probably should have used a helper method to avoid having a large chunk of code, but it does the job. :)

```
namespace CodingChallenges
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class Solution
    {
        // Returns the number of perfect substrings of repeating character value 'num'.
        public static int PerfectSubstring(string str, int num)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int startOfSliceIndex = 0; startOfSliceIndex < str.Length - 1; startOfSliceIndex++)
            {
                for (int endofSliceIndex = startOfSliceIndex + 1; endofSliceIndex < str.Length; endofSliceIndex++)
                {
                    Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
                    string slice = str.Substring(startOfSliceIndex, (endofSliceIndex - startOfSliceIndex) + 1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < slice.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (dict.ContainsKey(slice[i]))
                        {
                            dict[slice[i]]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dict[slice[i]] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    bool isPerfect = true;
                    foreach (var entry in dict)
                    {
                        if (entry.Value != num)
                        {
                            isPerfect = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isPerfect)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(slice);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(count + " perfect substring.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(count + " perfect substrings.");
            }
            return count;
        }


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test = "1102021222";
            PerfectSubstring(test, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in **O(n*D)**

I think it can be upgraded to be **O(n)** by replacing the `hash_map(frozenset(head_sum_mod_k.items()))` with a map implementation that updates its hash rather than recalculating it -
this can be done because only one entry of head_sum_mod_k is changed per iteration.

```
from copy import deepcopy

def countKPerfectSequences(string:str, k):
    print(f'Processing \'{string}\', k={k}')
    # init running sum
    head_sum = {char: 0 for char in string}
    tail_sum = deepcopy(head_sum)
    tail_position = 0
    # to match both 0 & k sequence lengths, test for mod k == 0
    head_sum_mod_k = deepcopy(head_sum)
    occurrence_positions = {frozenset(head_sum_mod_k.items()): [0]}
    # iterate over string
    perfect_counter = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(string):
        head_sum[val] += 1
        head_sum_mod_k[val] = head_sum[val] % k
        while head_sum[val] - tail_sum[val] > k:
            # update tail to avoid longer than k sequnces
            tail_sum[string[tail_position]] += 1
            tail_position += 1
        # print(f'str[{tail_position}..{i}]=\'{string[tail_position:i+1]}\', head_sum_mod_k={head_sum_mod_k} occurrence_positions={occurrence_positions}')
        # get matching sequences between head and tail
        indices = list(filter(lambda i: i >= tail_position, occurrence_positions.get(frozenset(head_sum_mod_k.items()), [])))
        # for start in indices:
        #     print(f'{string[start:i+1]}')
        perfect_counter += len(indices)
        # add head
        indices.append(i+1)
        occurrence_positions[frozenset(head_sum_mod_k.items())] = indices
    return perfect_counter
```